# White screen before loading a SplashViewController xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Im trying to make animated splash view controller,
so i have made the Launch Image file : Main.storyboard 
and my splash screen loads before the login page, everything works fine but i see a white screen for a sec.  is there any way to avoid it?

here is my Storyboard: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just selected LunchScreen.storyboard as launch screen again and make a picture that looks the same as animated splash scpeen so for now it shows a picture than start to animate